# Where do we mention iBeacon support in iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

Our iOS application has support for iBeacon. It was submitted to Appstore for review. During the review the app was rejected ("metadata rejected") asking for more information. The following is the message from Apple.

"We noticed that your application's description specifically mentions iBeacon functionality. We did not see any iBeacon functionality selected in iTunes Connect"

But I could not find a place in iTunes connect where we should specifically mention about iBeacon support. Could you please let me know if you have an idea?  (We have already include the details in the app description. But this seems to be not enough).

Comment: Never seen anything like that either in iTunes connect; Just respond to Apple asking for clarification.

Comment: Yes. Submitted some additional information and asked for some more clarifications to Apple. Will await their response.

Answer (score 2):

This may be just a poorly worded response.  When submitting beacon-enabled apps to the App Store for review, you need to do two things to keep reviewers happy:

1. Provide a text description of how beacons trigger functionality in the app.
2. Attach a video of the app in action, showing how beacons affect its user interface.  The text notes for reviewers should describe how beacons are triggering the app in the video.  Reviewers rely on these videos because they typically don't have access to hardware beacons to trigger the functionality, and wouldn't have the time to do so even if they did.

Remember that reviewers are humans and make mistakes and give poorly worded responses.  Since you want to get your app approved, it is in your interests to make it as easy as possible for reviewers to let your app through the process.

Comment: Thanks David. Have not provided the second item you mentioned. Will prepare and submit one.